# Big O notation simplification from sum

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

On calculating the convexity of an optimization problem, I am getting a term $O(\sqrt{n+m}(n)^3)$. Here both $m$ and $n$ are parameters. Is there any way I can simplify this term to write it as a product?
I know that if time complexity $T(n,m)=O(\sqrt{n+m}(n)^3)$, then $\exists C,M $ such that $\vert T(n,m) \vert \leq C\vert \sqrt{n+m}(n)^3 \vert $ when either $n,m \geq M$.
I need the simplification for the interpretation of the algorithm. (Like, if time complexity is $O(n)$, then if $n$ is multiplied by 10, then the time complexity is also multiplied by 10. But it seems such an interpretation is not possible in the above case, as $m$ and $n$ are independent terms in summation).

Comment: As $\sqrt{n}<n^3\sqrt{n+m}$ and $\sqrt{m}<n^3\sqrt{n+m}$, then you cannot estimate $n^3\sqrt{n+m}$ with upper bound dependent only on one variable.

Comment: I assume that $n/m$ means "both $n$ and $m$", and not the quotient ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I meant `n` or `m`.

Comment: Better write $n,m\ge M$. (And I doubt that the *or* interpretation be correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are after a substitution like$$\sqrt{n+m}\,n^3\le f(n)\,g(m),$$ or equivalently

$$n+m\le p(n)\,q(m).$$

If you freeze $m$, then $p(n)=\Omega(n)$ must hold (and similarly $q(m)=\Omega(m)$). So I see no better solution than

$$\sqrt{n+m}\,n^3\le\sqrt{nm}\,n^3= n^{7/2}m^{1/2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply $m$ by $10$, the magnitude of the term varies by a factor

$$\sqrt{\frac{n+10m}{n+m}}=\sqrt{\frac{\frac nm+10}{\frac nm+1}}.$$

That factor stays in range $\left(1,\sqrt{10}\right)$ and varies relatively little as a function of $\frac nm$.

If you multiply $n$ by $10$, the magnitude varies by $1000$ times a similar factor.

So it is not very wrong to explain the complexity as "roughly $n^{7/2}$".